# Specific user content Add, Edit, Delete particular data for particular user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm starting to organize a project with a few models, but the two main models in question are Brands and Products.

I will allow clients to login on Django Admin site to edit their Brands and to Add, Edit and Delete their own Products.

However when editing their Products, said client will only be able to Add, Edit & Delete their own Products; so for example their Brand Name will already be chosen in the Foreign Key dropdown, due to the permission constrain. From there they can repeat the process of adding their Brands and Delete and Edit the Brands as they Choose.

## Current Setup & Problem

Currently I have this setup for Brands the way I would like, just for a client to see only their Brands to Edit. But for Products, they can see *all* the products, even for different Brands (which is not what I want); and when they create a new product they have to choose from a dropdown of products to match with (which is not what I want). I am using the default Django permissions as of now, with some ModelAdmin methods.

## models.py

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract base class model that provides self updating
    ``created`` and ``modified`` fields.
    """

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    # Metadata
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Brand(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Information for each brand
    """

    # Primary Key
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    # General information
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="", unique=True)
    brand_description = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    brand_origin_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    brand_origin_state_or_country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="",
        help_text=_('State (USA only), Country (International only)'), verbose_name=_('State or Country'))
    brand_feature_image = CloudinaryField('Featured Brand Image', null=True, blank=True)
    brand_isActive = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Brand active'))

    # Metadata
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name = _('Brand')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Brands')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format( self.brand_name )

class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Product for each brand
    """

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="", verbose_name=_('Product Name') )
    product_url = models.URLField(max_length=100, blank=True,  default="",
        help_text=_('This is for the product web url to the particular item on your website.'), verbose_name=_('Product Url'))
    product_price = CurrencyField( verbose_name=_('Product price') )
    product_image = CloudinaryField('Product Image', blank=True,  null=True)

    # Foreign Key
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', null=True, to_field="id")

    #Metadata
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name = _('Product')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Products')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format( self.product_name )
```

## Admin.py

```
class BrandAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["brand_name", "brand_origin_city", "brand_origin_state_or_country"]
    search_fields = ["brand_name"]
    list_per_page = 10  

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super(BrandAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

        obj.save()

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(BrandAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(brand_name=request.user)

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["product_name","product_price"]
    search_fields = ["product_name"]
    list_per_page = 20  

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user

        super(ProductAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

        obj.save()

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(brand=request.user)


# Register Models below
admin.site.register(Brand, BrandAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

What would be a solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
      ...
      return qs.filter(brand__brand_name = request.user)
```

Hope this work. Let me know if not.